# How to get two concurrent threads to listen to one input?

Tags: c, pthreads, getchar, simultaneous

I'm making a multithreaded console game where I have to move an actor and shoot the enemies. Moving and shooting are two different threads and they both must listen to the keyboard input.

I've tried listening to the input in the while loop in main function and passing it by address to both threads, where an infinite loop is processing this character but this way the actor just jumps into the corners, my guess is that these loops are processing the character very fast and the character stays the same even after one key pressed, so the thread moves an actor every time the loop positively checks the character

If I put `getchar()` in both threads, only one of them will be functional.

```
int main() {

...
  do {
    cur_c = getchar();
    if(!created){

    pthread_create(&funcs[0], NULL, shot, (void *) &cur_c);
    pthread create(&funcs[1], NULL, actor, (void *) &cur_c);

    created = true;
    } 

    if(...)
       break;

  } while (1);

...
}


}
void *actor(void *ch)
{
   pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);
   int *cur_char = ch;
   while(1){
     switch(*cur_char){
       case 'w':
         goUp();
         break;
       case 'a':
         goLeft();
         break;
        ...
      }

   }

   pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void *shot(void *ch)
{
   pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);
   int *cur_char = ch;
   while(1){
     if(*cur_char == ' ') {
       Position pos = ...;
       fire(&pos);
     }
   }
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

I expect both of these functions to listen for an input but this way:
if I press `' '` the actor will fire once or if I press `'w'` will move up once and not until I press any other key. 
My question is whether it is possible to make `getchar()` in separate threads listen to an input simultaneously? If so, how is it possible?

Comment: So create a third thread, one could call it "event dispatcher" or similar, that listens for events generated by the user and has pipes or other inter-thread communication channel opened to both "moving" and "shooting" thread. For each received event, the "event dispatcher" sends the event to the chosen thread.

Comment: Is this the only way to accomplish the simultaneous listening for the same input stream for two threads?

Comment: No it isn't, @JamesToaster, but it gets around numerous issues, such as what to do when the movement thread reads the keystroke for a "shoot" command.

Comment: Were it me, however, I would not be using multiple threads in the first place.  Doing everything in the same thread would get around numerous additional issues, such as keeping movement speed consistent with bullet speed, resolving confusion around obtaining and handling input, and managing the display.